# How do I reuse a jquery click function?

Tags: jquery

I have a set of `<li>` having a `.pro` class applied. Each of these list items displays a specific slider when clicked. I have some JQuery code to control the hide and show behavior, but for each `<li>` I have used separate show and hide snippets making the whole code lengthy.

How can I refactor my code (below) to reduce the amount of code ?

```javascript
$(".pro1").click(function(){
    $(".slider2").hide();

    $(".slider1").show();
});

$(".pro2").click(function(){
    $(".slider1").hide();

    $(".slider2").show();
});
```

and it continues infinitely...

Comment: `$(".pro").each()` , [jquery.each](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.each/)

Comment: could u please specify...am new to jquery and js

Comment: There are several ways to do this. If you could provide some of your HTML to show the context and a few more of the looped functions, it would be easier to come up with a solution that works. Right now I'm asking myself a few questions. Are you toggling only two sliders or are there more? Are all the list item classnames `.pro` or are they `.pro1`, `.pro2`, `.pro3` etc? Is there a relation between the list item that is clicked and the slider that is shown or hidden? :o)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have to assign a different class for each `li`, you just need to use one class, and use it to loop all your `li`s.

The loop can be done using [jquery.each()](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.each/) method.

Now, for each one of the `li`, we need to hide a specific slider and show another. Means that we need to get the value of the slide that we want to show. To do that, we can store the value of the next slide in the `li`. For this, we can use [HTML data-* attributes](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_global_data.asp).

This code should help you :

```js
$(".mySlide").hide();

$('.pro').click(function(){
    var li = $(this);
    nextSlide = li.attr("data-show");
    $(".mySlide").hide();
    $("#"+nextSlide).show();
});
```

```css
.mySlide{
  background-color : red;
  height : 50px;
  width : 100px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
<li class='pro' data-show='slide1'>Slide 1</li>
<li class='pro' data-show='slide2'>Slide 2</li>
<li class='pro' data-show='slide3'>Slide 3</li>
<li class='pro' data-show='slide4'>Slide 4</li>
<li class='pro' data-show='slide5'>Slide 5</li>
</ul>
<br>
<div class='mySlide' id='slide1'> 
 <h3> This is slide 1 </h3>
</div>
<div class='mySlide' id='slide2'> 
 <h3> This is slide 2 </h3>
</div>
<div class='mySlide' id='slide3'> 
 <h3> This is slide 3 </h3>
</div>
<div class='mySlide' id='slide4'> 
 <h3> This is slide 4 </h3>
</div>
<div class='mySlide' id='slide5'> 
 <h3> This is slide 5 </h3>
</div>
```

Comment: Do you need to wrap the `.click()` inside an `.each()`? `$('.pro').each(function(){    $(this).click(function(){ ... })    })` Seems a bit verbose. Why not simply go with `$('.pro').click(...)`?